# Cache all models in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, caching, models

I need to cache (and expire) all the models in a table.

For example, if i have a model named Currency, i only have less than 10 possible currencies. Therefore, it would be nice to have:

```
class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  cache_all(:expire_in => 10.minutes)
end
```

so that

```
Currency.all
Currency.find_by_name("USD")
```

should not hit the DB.

What do you think it could be a good approach?

Also, if you believe it would be better to use a model that is not backed up by a DB, please comment on this. Please notice that i would like to have a AR-style association.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the data set is so small, probably the best thing is to cache it in local memory. There are a couple ways to do this, one is to use [Memoization like I show here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207606/use-find-to-initialize-a-constant/1215306#1215306). However that isn't the most efficient because it will store the `all` method and `find_by_name` method in separate caches even though they are the same object.

An alternative is to redefine the methods to cache the objects manually. Something like this.

```
class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all
    @all_cache ||= super.map(&:freeze) # freeze so you don't modify the cached objects
  end

  def self.find_by_name(name)
    all.detect { |c| c.name.to_s.downcase == name.to_s.downcase }
  end

  def self.flush_all_cache
    @all_cache = nil
  end
end
```

There may be a plugin to handle this for you, but I haven't looked into that at all.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan :). I have also found the cached_model gem, but it seems a little old.. i will give it a try.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you are running multiple servers, if the data changes, you will have to clear the in-memory cache on _all_ servers, not just the one that changed the data.