# Catch-22: Rails db migration doesn't run when class constants make db calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a class similar to the following:

```
class FruitKinds < ActiveRecord::Base
  Apple = FruitKinds.find(:all).find { |fk|
    fk.fruit_name == :apple.to_s
  }

  # ... other fruits

  # no methods
end
```

Apple and other specific Fruits are commonly used as default values elsewhere in my application, so I want a handy means to refer to them in an enumerable, static-ish way.

However, there's a problem. There is a database migration to create the `FruitKinds` table and populate it with the special `Fruits` like `Apple`. When the database migration runs to initialize FruitKinds, `rake` fails to start because it first loads `FruitKinds`, which then makes a call to the database, which of course fails since the FruitKinds table is not yet there.

The workaround is to comment out the FruitKinds::* fields while the migration runs, but that is awful and hacky. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty common gotcha, to the point that I now consider any database access at the class definition level an antipattern.  The alternative is to make it a lazy property.  The simplest way to do this is simply to make it a class-level method instead of a constant.  Note that you can have capitalised methods in Ruby, so you can make it look like a constant if you want:

```
class FruitKinds < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.Apple 
    @apple ||= FruitKinds.find(:all).find { |fk|
      fk.fruit_name == :apple.to_s
    }
  end

  # ... other fruits

  # no methods
end
```

Or if you want to get fancy you can use `const_missing` to dynamically create the constant the first time it is accessed.

As a side note, that's about the most inefficient way possible to find a record by name ;-)

Comment: Couldn't you write self.Apple such that it hits the db a maximum of once? You could save the value to a field somewhere and have an attr_accessor.

Comment: I was leaving memoization as an exercise to the reader, but there - I've changed the code above to save the value in a class variable.

Comment: BTW, any reason you're not just using `FruitKinds.find_first_by_fruit_name("apple")` for the find?

Comment: This is Rails 2.2, and I think that was introduced in 2.3, but I'm not sure. I tried it and it didn't seem to work, and there's no analogously named find_first_by_* methods.

Comment: The find_by_* methods are generated automatically.  See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html under "Dynamic attribute-based finders".  They have been available for quite a while, you should be fine in 2.2.

Comment: In any case at least consider doing `FruitKinds.find(:first, :conditions => { :fruit_name => "apple" })` or something along those lines (my AR is a little rusty).  That `find(:all)` hurts me to look at.

Answer (score 0):

As Avdi mentioned, you'll want to avoid interacting with the database when the class is loaded. If you're wanting to cache database records in local memory, I recommend using the Memoization feature added in Rails 2.2. [See my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207606/use-find-to-initialize-a-constant/1215306#1215306) for details.